# Calling javascript function using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $post_string=$_POST;
    $enc_string=json_encode($post_string);
    print("<script>encfunction('$enc_string');</script>");
    }
```

this is my javascript code

```
<script>
function encfunction(data)
{
alert("data");  
alert("hello");
alert("I am an alert box!");
} 
</script>
```

I want to get the result in that function because i have to sent  json response using ajax but it shows:`Uncaught ReferenceError: encfunction is not defined`.

I referred following links but it doesn't give the desired result:
[Javascript Uncaught Reference error Function is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676604/javascript-uncaught-reference-error-function-is-not-defined)

[Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick)

[Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737525/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-jquery)

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions have to be defined before they are called.  Make sure your first block of code containing the call to the encfunction appears in your html document after it has been declared (in your second block of code).  A better option is to define your function within the head element of the document.